# Autofilling an input field using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following form:

```
<form method='post' id='myform'>

    <div class="typeahead__container">
        <div class="typeahead__field">
            <input type="text" class="item" placeholder="Item" id='item' name='input_val'>
        </div>
    </div>

    <input type="text" class="id" placeholder="ID" id='item-id' name='input_val'>

    <button name="button" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm f-14 mr-1">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

And the following function to handle live search:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  // Defining the local dataset
  $.getJSON('http://127.0.0.1:8000/tst/', function(data) {
    console.log(data)

    let data = {
        "results": [
          { "item": "First",  "id": "1847" },
          { "item": "Second", "id": "4442" },
          { "item": "Third",  "id": "3847" }
        ]
    };

    //LIVE-SEARCH
    $(() => {

      $('#item').typeahead({
        source: {
          data: data.results.map(record => record.item)
        },
        callback: {
          onInit: function($el) {
            console.log(`Typeahead initiated on: ${$el.prop('tagName')}#${$el.attr('id')}`);
          }
        }
      });

    });
    //END LIVE-SEARCH

  });
});
```

I want to add another function to fill the default value of the input field `item-id` according to what the user chooses on the input field `item`. So, for example, if the user writes `First`, JQuery should set the default value of `item-id` to `1847` (see my previous block of code).

How can i do that? Am i supposed to do that inside my live search function or should i use another function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your code, I assume you are using Bootstrap Typeahead which uses an `updater` callback that we can use in this situation.

I hosted this static Json to bring a solution with a close syntax.

**Solution 1 : Using [Bootstrap Typeahead](https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead)** (may be useful to someone else)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('input#item').typeahead({
        
     source:  function (query, process) {
        return $.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/hi1oo', function (data) {
          //console.log(data);
          //data = $.parseJSON(data);
             return process(data.results);
         });
     },
        display : 'item',
        displayText: function(data){ return data.item;},
        val :  function(data){ return data;},

        updater: function (data) {
            
            $('#item-id').val(data.id);
            return data.item;
            }
        
 }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-3-typeahead/4.0.2/bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js" integrity="sha256-LOnFraxKlOhESwdU/dX+K0GArwymUDups0czPWLEg4E=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<form method='post' id='myform'>

    <div class="typeahead__container">
        <div class="typeahead__field">
            <input type="text" class="item" placeholder="Item" id='item' name='input_val' autocomplete="off">
        </div>
    </div>

    <input type="text" class="id" placeholder="ID" id='item-id' name='input_val'>

    <button name="button" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm f-14 mr-1">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

P.S : If your json is a result of a real-time search query where you look for item names and get this kind of data. Then you better change the `source` into something like following :

```
source:  function (query, process) {
return $.get('inc/ajaxh.php', { query: query }, function (data) {
        return process(data.results);
    });
},
```

**Solution 2 : using [jQuery Typeahead](https://github.com/running-coder/jquery-typeahead/)**

This one uses the callback onClickAfter. Notice that I made some changes on how you are mapping your data' response array and choose what to be displayed then use the item.id in the callback function.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  // Defining the local dataset
  $.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/hi1oo', function(data) {

    //LIVE-SEARCH
    $(() => {

      $('#item').typeahead({
        source: {
          //data: data.results.map(record => record.item)
          data: data.results
        },
        display: ["item"],
        callback: {
            //I called it itemx to avoid confusion with available "#item"
            onClickAfter: function (node, a, itemx, event) {
                $('#item-id').val(itemx.id);
                //alert('click');
        }
    }
      });

    });
    //END LIVE-SEARCH

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-typeahead/2.11.0/jquery.typeahead.min.js" integrity="sha256-q6QA5qUPfpeuxzP5D/wCMcvsYDsV6kQi5/tti+lcmlk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<form method='post' id='myform'>

    <div class="typeahead__container">
        <div class="typeahead__field">
            <input type="text" class="item" placeholder="Item" id='item' name='input_val'>
        </div>
    </div>

    <input type="text" class="id" placeholder="ID" id='item-id' name='input_val'>

    <button name="button" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm f-14 mr-1">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Hey, i'm sorry for not being more specific, my bad; i'm using this library: https://github.com/running-coder/jquery-typeahead/

Comment: It's Ok :) and is it a static json or a Live search like in your code' comments? I don't see an input parameter...

Comment: In my live code, the data is retrieved from the API that it is called, in this code i'm using the variable data as muppet data!

Comment: After the update, I think the solution 2 is considered as an accepted answer :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll make a bounty as soon as i can!